# Facebook Login Issue In React Native

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-login

I integrated Facebook login in my app.

If my device have Facebook app and i am trying to login from my app it showing error and i am not able to login but when I remove Facebook app from my device and try to login, It works.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I am using this code

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"])
    .then((loginResult) => {
      if (loginResult.isCancelled) {
        CustomAlert('Échec de connexion avec Facebook');
        console.log(loginResult);
      } else {
        this.getFacebookData();
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      CustomAlert('Échec de la connexion avec erreur: ' + error);
    })
```

If there is an issue it must not be login without native app.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You are logging in with the same Facebook account or different.

Comment: @Mohammed Ashfaq trying with different account also